# Unique smooth structure on an embedded submanifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

I was reading this proposition in Lee's book and I had two questions concerning it.

> **Proposition 5.2** (Images of Embeddings as Submanifolds). Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold with or without boundary, $N$ is a smooth
>   manifold, and $F : N \to M$ is a smooth embedding. Let $S = F(N)$ With
>   the subspace topology, $S$ is a topological manifold, and it has a
>   unique smooth structure making it into an embedded submanifold of $M$
>   with the property that $F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image.
>
> *Proof.* If we give S the subspace topology that it inherits from $M$; then the assumption that $F$ is an embedding means that $F$ can be
>   considered as a homeomorphism from $N$ onto $S$ , and thus $S$ is a
>   topological manifold. We give S a smooth structure by taking the
>   smooth charts to be those of the form $(F(U),\phi \circ F^{-1})$,
>   where $(U,\phi)$ is any smooth chart for N ; smooth compatibility of
>   these charts follows immedi- ately from the smooth compatibility of
>   the corresponding charts for $N$. With this smooth structure on $S$ ,
>   the map $F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image (essentially by
>   definition), and this is obviously the only smooth structure with this
>   property. The inclusion map $S \hookrightarrow M$ M is equal to the
>   composition of a diffeomorphism followed by a smooth embedding:
>   $S \xrightarrow{F^{-1}} N \xrightarrow{F} M$
>   - and therefore it is a smooth embedding.

How do we show that

> this is obviously the only smooth structure with this property

Also if we take the basic example where $F=\iota$ the inclusion map, then the structure we define on $S$ should be $(\iota^{-1}(U),\phi \circ \iota)= (U\cap S, \phi|_S)$ no? And not $(\iota(U),\phi \circ \iota^{-1})$ right?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $F(N)$ has a smooth structure such that $F$ is diffeomorphism onto its image. If $(U,\phi)$ be a smooth chart on $N$, then our assumption implies that $U$ is diffeomorphic with $F(U)$. Since $(U,\phi)$ is a smooth chart, $U$ and $\phi(U)$ are diffeomorphic. Therefore $F(U)$ and $\phi(U)$ are diffeomorphic via $\phi\circ F^{-1}$. This defines a smooth chart of $F(N)$. If we have an open cover of $N$ by smooth charts, say $\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}_{i\in I}$, then $\{(F(U_i),\phi_i\circ F^{-1})\}_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of $F(N)$. Obviously these charts are compatible, so they form a smooth atlas for $F(N)$.

Indeed, what I've proved is: assume that $F(N)$ has already given a smooth structure with the desired property and $(U,\phi)$ a smooth chart of $N$, then $(F(U),\phi\circ F^{-1})$ is a smooth chart *in this smooth structure*. Smooth charts of this form covers $F(N)$, so they define the given smooth structure as well. Hence the smooth structure we've assumed must be given by charts of the form $(F(U),\phi\circ F^{-1})$.

In your example, it should be less confused if you specify your domain and target. You want to have a smooth chart of $\iota(N)$, not $N$. For $U$ is a chart in $N$ then the corresponded chart in $\iota(N)$ is $\iota(U)$. You're taking $U$ as a chart in $M$ and deduce a chart $\iota^{-1}(U)$ in $N$.

Comment: Sorry, it is not so clear for me. If I understand correctly, you say that given a diffeomorphism $F: A \to B$ between two manifolds, if we chose a smooth-structure one one, there is only one possible smooth-structure on the other? I understand that given a structure on $A$ then $(V, \phi \circ F^{-1})$ is a structure on $B$ but I don't get why it is the only one.

Comment: Dear @roi_saumon, when we say that there is a diffeomorphism, it must be that the smooth structures on $A$ and $B$ was given at the start. Here what I argue is: *If $F:A\to B$ is a homeomorphism and $A$ was given a smooth structure, then there is one and only smooth structure on $B$ such that $F$ is a diffeomorphism*. I'll edit my answer to be clearer.

Comment: I've edit my answer. It turns out to be quite difficult to write down explicitly what I mean but I hope that it's clearer now.

Comment: So if I assume as you said that $F(N)$ has already been given a smooth-structure, let's call it $\{(V_i,\psi_i)\}_{i\in J}$. Also we know that $(F(U),\phi\circ F^{-1})$ are charts as well for this structure and that they cover $F(N)$. So it seems to me that we have to show that charts $(V,\psi)$ and a chart $(F(U),\phi \circ F^{-1})$ are compatible no?

Comment: Yes. This is evident, since they belong to the same smooth structure. Conversely, any charts compatible with all $(F(U),\phi\circ F^{-1})$ is belong to the given smooth structure.

Comment: Is it obvious? I should have said : **Also we know that $(F(U),ϕ∘F^{−1})$ are charts if they are compatible with the $(V_i,\psi_i)$**. So we don't know they are in the same smooth structure unless we know there are compatible, no? There is something I don't get it seems...